# How to convert a very tall image to a pdf with many pages?

Tags: pdf, acrobat

Imagine to open a PDF document of 100 pages and capture it with one software for screen capturing as a scrolling window.

You would get a very tall images with all 100 pages in only one jpeg.

I want to convert it back to a PDF of 100 pages. But Acrobat takes it as a very tall one page only document.

How can I solve?

Comment: Do you want a ready-made tool? Or would a small programming task also do?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if there is such a ready tool, I could merely point towards a programming sample which would have to be tweaked for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Found a third party software that meets my needs. It's not really good but it works and it's free. If you know a better one let me know.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/posterazor/?source=dlp